# can WiX be used to create windows service for any console application

Tags: windows-services, wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am new to WiX and I've been trying to use it to create a installer for a basic console application which just prints hello world in console and hangs there. 
My question is, can WiX be used to create windows service for any console application?

I know that it can be used to create service installer for windows service application.

i did create installer for windows service for the console application, and while installing i get

```
Service failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'create windows service for any console application'?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a console application can be a service because it will be trying to create a console window, and running a console windows with the system account is very dubious, and it won't interact with the desktop. Console apps aren't windows services.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  You need to use a helper (Service host wrapper) such as srvany.exe  and then have WiX define a service for srvany.    Service Control Manager will send a start command to the service which will start wrvany.exe and then srvany.exe will read an additional registry value to know what EXE to call.  For more details see:

[Wix installer to replace INSTSRV and SRVANY for user defined service installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595338/wix-installer-to-replace-instsrv-and-srvany-for-user-defined-service-installatio)